# Trying to open another userform

Tags: vba, excel

Ok this seems extremely basic and I apologize for that.  All I need to do is once a user clicks a button in form1, it gets hidden and form2 is shown.  However, I keep getting Run-time error 4248, and I have already checked google for any help.  Any suggestions to what might be causing this would be much appreciated.

I will show my code below, but first let me tell you things I have attempted:

- I have tried reactivating the excel file before calling the hide/show
  statements,
- I have tried saving the file before calling hide/show,
- I have tried separating the commands out to 2 buttons,
- I have tried renaming the forms.

  ```
  Private Sub but_Start_Click()
  Worksheets("Data").Range("B1:B1").Value = Me.tb_ProjectName.Value
  Form1.Hide
  Form2.Show
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: I can't replicate this: I have tried exactly your code above (down to using the same names) and it works.  Can you give any more info (version of Excel, which line is causing the error, any other event handlers in either form)?

Answer (score 0):

I just created two forms, `UserForm1` and `UserForm2`.  I put a button on the first and in the code for the button click event (within the form) I have (as you have):

```
UserForm1.Hide
UserForm2.Show
```

The button, when clicked, hides the first form and shows the second.

Comment: Yeah as it should, I don't know whats causing this issue.  I have no clue, worked in first round of testing and now that Im almost finished with the whole project this error shows up, driving me crazy lol

Comment: Why the down votes? I'm helping the OP understand that the code that's posted is not incorrect, no?

Comment: Im not sure why they down voted, maybe its an issue others are having?

Comment: Well, anyway, I guess the problem you're having is not with the code you've posted.  Must be some other issue.  Maybe try removing things until it works.

Comment: @newb101, the downvotes are probably because this doesn't actually answer the question.  Better to use comments to clarify, then post an answer when it's solved.

Comment: Ah, okay that's fair thank you.  I've never commented on a question before (just got the rep)... Now I know.  Thanks.

Comment: @newb101 no problem.  (Also you can delete your answer and you'll get back the rep the downvotes cost you.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I feel like an idiot after two days of trying to figure out the issue.  After aucuparia's response I went back and checked all of the useforms' initialize statements and found a activedocument.close statement that was leftover from a previous step.  Thanks for all of the help and time you all have spent on this silly question.  Guess bone headed stuff happens to the best of us lol.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot show 2 userforms by using

```
Userform1.show
userform2.show
```

because the first one already blocks all excell functions and stuf (try clicking on your worksheet xhen the Userform1 is opened)

the way arround is:

```
Userform1.show false
userform2.show false
```

without hiding the first userform, or unloading it.

(also note that userform1.hide keeps its values, but unload userform1 reinitializes them).